# What type do vector strings deduce to?

Tags: c++, string, vector, type-deduction

I'm becoming familiar with using vectors (reading [An introduction to std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/)), and it displays the following code as an example:

```
// as with std::array, the type can be omitted since C++17
std::vector array4 { 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 }; // deduced to std::vector<int>
```

If I use this C++17 style vector initialization with string literals, what type will the vector deduce (i.e. `std::string`, `char*`, etc)?

```
std::vector strArray {"Hello", "world", "!!!"};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (i.e. std::string

No, string literals are not related to the class `std::string`. Technically this could happen if vector had a special deduction guide for this, but it doesn't.

> ... char*

No, string literals are const.

The contained type will be deduced as `const char*`.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add that the string literals have type `const char[N]`, where N is the number of characters including the terminator, and the vector's list-initializer constructor takes values and not references, thus the literals decay to the pointers `const char*`.

If you want a vector of std::strings,  you can use literal `operator ""s`:

```
std::vector strArray {"Hello"s, "world"s, "!!!"s};
```

is the same as

```
std::vector<std::string> strArray {"Hello", "world", "!!!"};
```